# Kotlin top level method not visible between modules in mixed Kotlin + Java Maven project

Tags: maven, kotlin, compilation

I have multi-module Java project. In one of the modules, there is [a top level Kotlin function](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit/blob/master/json-unit-assertj/src/main/kotlin/net/javacrumbs/jsonunit/assertj/JsonAssertionsDsl.kt#L18) which is accessible when [called inside the module](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit/blob/kotlin-fix/json-unit-assertj/src/test/kotlin/net/javacrumbs/jsonunit/assertj/JsonAssertionsDslKtTest.kt#L10) but not accessible from different module. See the failing test [here](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit/pull/300). To make it even more confusing, when executed through `mvn clean test` all test pass, but when executed using `mvn clean package`, the compilation fails. I suspect it's something related to `kotlin_module` file missing in JAR file, but since it's poorly documented, I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by OSGi bundle plugin that was missing `Include-Resource` directive to add files from `target/classes/META-INF`. See [this](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit/pull/300/commits/1c8c6b681201daffae530ab014b113399e7617c5) commit for details.